# Error "localStorage is not defined" al implementar servicio en constructor

Tags: c#, angular, local-storage

estoy haciendo un proyecto y al querer implementar un servicio en el concentrador, me arroja el error de "localStorage is not defined", ya importe el servicio pero sigue igual.
El servicio se ejecuta en otras partes y componentes de la app

Codigo de mi ApiauthService

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    })
  };
  
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApiauthService {
    url: string = 'https://localhost:7087/api/User/login';  
    private usuarioSubject: BehaviorSubject<Usuario>; 
    public usuario!: Observable<Usuario>;

    public get usuarioData(): Usuario{
      return this.usuarioSubject.value; 
    }

    constructor( private _http: HttpClient){
      console.log('Constructor ejecutado');
      this.usuarioSubject =new BehaviorSubject<Usuario>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario')!)) ;
      this.usuario = this.usuarioSubject.asObservable();
      console.log("Valor d usuario: " + this.usuarioData)
    }

    login(login: Login ) : Observable<Response>{
        return this._http.post<Response>(this.url, login, httpOptions).pipe(
          map( res=>{
            if(res.exito === 1){
              const usuario: Usuario = res.data;
              localStorage.setItem('usuario', JSON.stringify(usuario));
              this.usuarioSubject.next(usuario);
            }
            return res;
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
            throw error; // Puedes manejar el error según tus necesidades
          })
        );
    }
    logOut(){
      localStorage.removeItem('usuario');
      this.usuarioSubject.next( null as any);
    }
}
```

Codigo de mi componente

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 [x: string]: any;
 title = 'ventasANG';
  // usuario!: Usuario;
  
  ;
  
  constructor(public apiauth: ApiauthService, private router: Router ){
    this.apiauth.usuario.subscribe(res =>{
      console.log("Cambio de objeto " + res);
    })
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("valores en componente app " + this.apiauth.usuarioData)
  }

  logout(){
    this.apiauth.logOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

He intentado importando y viendo si se ejecuta el servicio en otros componentes, y no me marca error, solo al ejecutarlo en el app.component

Comment: ¿Tienes habilitado Server Side Rendering? en el servidor no tienes localStorage